# Sudo not found. Trying npm install

Tags: windows, node.js, sudo

I am using a Windows 8.1 laptop.  I keep getting sudo not found.  Trying npm install with the following command:

```
F:\Webruin2>sudo npm install -g git
'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

F:\Webruin2>npm install -g git
git@0.1.5 C:\Users\Dave\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\git
└── mime@1.2.9

F:\Webruin2>git -v
'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

F:\Webruin2>npm install -s sudo
sudo@1.0.3 node_modules\sudo
├── inpath@1.0.2
├── pidof@1.0.2
└── read@1.0.5 (mute-stream@0.0.4)

F:\Webruin2>sudo npm install -g git
'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Please let me know the best way to proceed.  If this is off topic, please help me get it back on topic. ;)

Tim

Comment: Sudo is a built-in unix/linux command, so I'm not sure how your windows machine would make sense of it.

I know this sounds snarky, and is probably not the answer you're looking for, but my honest recommendation would be to ditch your Windows computer for.. basically anything else. A macbook is nice if you can afford it, but if not, you'll probably have a nicer development experience by running ubuntu inside of VirtualBox.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The 'sudo' command will not be recognized by the Windows command prompt (cmd.exe) because 'sudo' is a Unix/Linux-based application which is only compatible with that particular operating system. Windows does not currently include or support this command.

On a Unix/Linux operating system, 'sudo' is an application used to temporarily gain the security privileges of another user (usually root/administrator), often for the purpose of software or driver installation, and is similar to running the Windows command prompt as administrator.

Based on the outputs you have posted, npm already appears to be installed on your system (as seen by the execution of "npm install -s sudo"), so you should be able to install npm modules with the command "npm install $modulename", with '$modulename' being replaced by the name of the module or library you wish to install.

If you are trying to install Git on your Windows platform, I recommend using the appropriate installer from: http://git-scm.com/download