# Reprogramming a dash button to send an SMS

Tags: javascript

I am working on the dash-sms hack here: https://github.com/sanzgiri/dash-sms. I was wondering if anyone could provide insight on once I configure the files and input my Twilio credentials, how do I run the program? I enter the command line prompt code, however, this returns an error or not found. Below is a screenshot of the folder I have the files in and what I entered in the command prompt window and not having any luck. Thanks to any insight provided!
[image]
[image]

Comment: `sudo` is not a command on Windows, that's the first problem. It will also require `node`, `npm` etc. Have you configured your system to write and run node programs?

Comment: you cannot use `sudo` on a plain-ol' windows command line (that's a linux thing) - so for starters, you need to make sure the commands you run are windows-compatible - having said that, if you already installed 'npm' and 'node' you might be able to type: `node index.js`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sudo not found. Trying npm install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29592228/sudo-not-found-trying-npm-install)

Comment: Thank you for the help! Could I run this in a virtual machine using Ubuntu?

Comment: Did you try like @ochi suggested "node index.js"? It's a node app, probably you don't need Ubuntu, but you need node for sure.

Comment: So I'm not sure if I'm doing this incorrectly. I downloaded  [https://nodejs.org/en/ ] in a virtual machine running Ubuntu v16. I also installed `npm`. I tried running the program using `sudo node index.js` and output: `sudo: node: command not found`, I tried installing `sudo npm install node-dash-button`. This returns a whole bunch of errors starting with `gyp ERR!`.